# MsAccess Uploading a file from a form Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a button that lets me select a file to choose, that location of the file gets saved to a textbox, I use the location from the textbox to upload a file to a data base and I get an error.

"An INSERT INTO query  cannot contain a multi-valued field."

Following is my code.

Private Sub btn_Browse_Click()

```
Dim f As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim varItem As Variant

Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
f.allowMultiSelect = True
If f.Show Then
For Each varItem In f.selectedItems
strFile = Dir(varItem)

strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
    "File: " & strFile

Me.txt_PicSource = strFolder + strFile
Next
End If
Set f = Nothing
```

...

```
CurrentDb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO Field_Return_Table(Date_FRL, Time_FRL, Client_FRL, Product_FRL, LOT_FRL, Territory_FRL, Tracking_FRL, Condition_FRL, Location_FRL, Completed_By_FRL, Comments_FRL, Attachment_FRL) " & _
        "VALUES ('" & strDate & "', '" & strDate & "', '" & Me.combo_Client.Value & "', '" & Me.txt_Product.Value & "', '" & Me.txt_Lot.Value & "', '" & Me.txt_Territory.Value & "', '" & Me.txt_Track.Value & "', '" & strCondition & "', '" & strLocation & "', '" & strUser & "', '" & Me.txt_Comment.Value & "', '" & Me.txt_PicSource.Value & "')"
```

...

Any tips of how to upload this file via the INSERT INTO?

Comment: Take a look at Field_Return_Table in design view. Are any of the fields multi value?

Comment: No, none of them are multi value. Before I added the upload feature, this worked perfectly fine. The Field Name where this is being stored is an Attachment data type.

Comment: See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd), and the link at the very end.

Comment: An Attachment field is a type of multi-value field. That link appears to be broken. Try this one http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/working-with-attachment-fields.html

Comment: Access has a 2GB size limit. Embedding files can quickly erode that limit.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to NOT attach any file to an Access Database. Your database will increase size, affecting performance, and getting high chances of corrupting. If you want need those files, just create a directory in the same path that database, and use Hyperlinks in your Access Database to link those files. Seriously, attaching files is one of the worst things to do in an Access Database.